# Get text to span over image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get it so text is over an image and when you hover over the image the text block extends. For example

This is before
[image: before]

This is after
[image: hovering]

So my html is this.

```
<a href="rentals.php" class="type"><img src="assets/images/page1_img1.jpg" alt=""><span class="type_caption">Sport</span></a>
<p></p>
<a href="rentals.php" class="type"><img src="assets/images/page1_img2.jpg" alt=""><span class="type_caption">Deluxe</span></a>
```

now here is the CSS for each of those classes.

Class Type

```
    .type {
    border: 1px solid #ebeaea;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 84px;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}

.type_caption {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 312px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: url(..bsite/assets/images/capt_bg.png) 0 0 repeat;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: bold;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding: 7px 30px 8px;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.type:hover .type_caption {
    width: 100%;
}

.type:hover .type_caption {
    width: 100%;
}

.type+.type {
    margin-top: 11px;
}

.type+.type+.type {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

it will show up with text over it but the back ground image never shows. the image location is 
E:\xampp\htdocs\Bsite\assets\images

any idea why this wont work?

This is what I get now.
[image: current]

Comment: Just thinking loudly: I've always found way easier to use a `div` with a `background: url('...')` and inside it the text to display over the image, rather than an `img` tag. This way the text is "naturally" over the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to work fine. Double check that the path to your capt_bg.png is correct. It looks like you're using "bsite" instead of "Bsite".

As a piece of advice: you have an opaque black background on your text. You don't need an image to achieve that. That's an unnecessary resource load and HTTP request. Try achieving that with a CSS property like:

```
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
```

The first three digits are the R,G,B values and the last number is the A - Alpha (opacity).

Comment: it was the link.  thanks!  also changed from image to css and it also worked! great plus and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

HTML:

```
<!-- Container with background image -->
<div id="image-01">

<!-- Container for text -->
  <div id="title">

    <h3>SPORT</h3>

  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* This removes unwanted margin and padding in jsfiddle, you may not need it */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#image-01 {
  position: relative; /* This is important for positioning the text properly */
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url("https://fraserfree.imgix.net/content/places/Jet-Ski-On-The-Water-Optimized.jpg?w=1740&h=980&fit=crop&crop=center&auto=format"); /* Background image */ 
  background-size: cover;
}

#title {
  position: absolute; /* This is important for positioning the text properly */
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  height: 50px;
  width: 50%; /* Variable, depending on how wide you want the text banner to be */
  line-height: 50px;
  transition: all 250ms ease-out; /* Smooth transition for banner */
}

/* Text styling */
h3 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 8px;
}

/* When you hover over #image-01, animate the width of #title from 50% to 100% */
#image-01:hover #title {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```css
   .type {
    border: 1px solid #ebeaea;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 84px;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    max-width: 500px;
}

.type_caption {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 40%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: black ;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: bold;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding: 7px 30px 8px;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;
    opacity: 0.7;

}
img{
  width: 100%
}

.type:hover .type_caption {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
     <a href="rentals.php" class="type">
       <img src="http://www.hamarbatsenter.no/assets/Uploads/VANNSCOOTER-1.jpg" alt="">
       <span class="type_caption">Sport</span>
      </a>
<br/>
      <a href="rentals.php" class="type">
       <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQWOmtjEGmZH8PEV2YvDQJPSG7ofwBnmcyrXhnrabAjhgcMPlhw6g" alt="">
       <span class="type_caption">Deluxe</span>
      </a>
```